# Accessing JS / jQuery variable outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I'm trying to declare a variable inside function and wants to make it available outside that function. I have gone through several Stackoverflow answers but still cant figure out.

```
script>
    (function() {
        var url
        $("#airline-select").change(function () {
            url = "{% url 'airline_year_financial_data' %}";
        });
        console.log(url)
    var httpRequest;
    makeRequest();

    // create and send an XHR request
    function makeRequest() {
        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = responseMethod;
        httpRequest.open('GET', url)
        httpRequest.send()
    }
    // Handle XHR Response
    function responseMethod () {
        if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
            if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                updateUISuccess(httpRequest.responseText)
                } else {
                    // Do something
                }
        }
    }
    // Handle XHR Success
    function updateUISuccess(responseText) {
        var response = JSON.parse(responseText)
        var a = $("#airline-select").val();

        var width = 500;
        var height = 300;
        var padding = 20;
        d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
                .attr("class", "waterfall-container")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
                .attr("style", "outline: thin solid")
        d3.select("svg")
            .selectAll("rect")
            .data(response)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
                .attr("x-axis", 200)
                .attr("y-axis", 300)
                .attr("width", 20)
                .attr("height", 200)
                .attr("fill", "blue")
    }

})();

</script>
```

It logs 'undefined' at the console which means the value of url inside the function is getting updated or not available outside the function. How can I do that?

Comment: You're logging the value immediately after you attach the event handler, before the event has happened. Are you asking how you can make your variable predict the future?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What is $('#airline-select') selecting? I suspect it is giving `undefined` because that element, which has an event listener (on change), has not yet been changed. In that case, because you declared `var url` (which is saying `var url = undefined`, logging `url` should correctly yield `undefined`

Comment: Thanks, I'm not really sure about fixing it. All I want is that, this url variable gets the new value and I can something with this url object outside the function.

Comment: What task needs to be performed outside of the event handler?

Comment: Why not do what you need to do inside the event handler?  Or define the "other functionality" in a function available at the same scope, and just call it from the handler, perhaps passing the value of `url` at that time...

Comment: I have updated the complete code now. Basically I want when user selects an element from drow down list targeting $('#airline-select'), the url updates with the value of new element in the drop down list

Comment: You can pass `url` to `makeRequest()` within `change` event `makeRequest(url)`

Comment: @guest271314 Do you mind editing the code with what you are saying and show it as an answer? Thx

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `$` before immediately invoked function expression, if you are expecting `jQuery()` alias for `.ready()` to be called when `document` has loaded `DOM` and `#airline-select` is defined in `document` at HTML.

You can pass `url` to `makeRequest()` within `change` event handler by defining an expected parameter at the function declaration.

```
$(function() {

    var httpRequst, url;

    $("#airline-select").change(function () {
      url = "{% url 'airline_year_financial_data' %}";
      makeRequest(url)
    });

    // create and send an XHR request
    function makeRequest(url) { // include `url` parameter at function
        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = responseMethod;
        httpRequest.open('GET', url)
        httpRequest.send()
    }
    //
})
```

Comment: If you are expecting `change` event to be dispatched immediately you can chain `.change()` to `$("#airline-select").change(function () {
      url = "{% url 'airline_year_financial_data' %}";
      makeRequest(url)
    }).change()`